# Rails: How to reset database on deployed staging? (heroku)

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, deployment

Hi in local I can reset my database as follows:

`rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed`

But we have a staging version deployed on heroku, the above commands do not work there

How to properly reset the database? we're using postgresql addon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `rake db:drop db:create` won't work in your heroku environment, instead you need to reset your postgresql using the following command

`heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_URL -a app_name`

After run the above command your database will be as new, then you need to run `rake db:migrate db:seed`

That's all, for get your HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_URL you need to go to the dashboard of your app and select the Heroku Postgres add-on, then in the dashboard of the add-on you will find this part:

Psql: heroku pg:psql --app grupoly-staging HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK

The HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK is the url of your postgredatabase

Answer (score 0):

You mean this:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
```